# Xcode 6: Operand of Postfix "!" should have optional type

Tags: xcode, swift

Running Xcode 6 Beta 7,

I'm trying to unwrap a dictionary called `detail`, with a key `categories` which is an array of `category` dictionaries. Each `category` is of type `[String : AnyObject]`

```
var category: [String: AnyObject] = detail!["categories"]![categoryIndex] as [String: AnyObject]
```

I get the error

```
Operand of Postfix "!" should have optional type, type is '(String, AnyObject)'
```

If I remove the exclamation point "!" as the compiler suggested

```
var category: [String: AnyObject] = detail!["categories"][categoryIndex] as [String: AnyObject]
```

I get the error

```
(String, AnyObject) does not have the member named `subscript`
```

Help!

Here is my `detail` declaration

```
var detail: [String : AnyObject]?
```

Comment: What type is detail.  Is it an optional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the compiler can't figure out how to cast the various `AnyObject`s when accessing them like that. You can get around it with some creative inline casting:

```
var category: [String: AnyObject]? = ((detail?["categories"] as AnyObject?) as? [[String: AnyObject]])?[categoryIndex]
```

It would nicer to separate those steps out though:

```
var categoriesObj: AnyObject? = detail?["categories"]
var categories: [[String: AnyObject]]? = categoriesObj as? [[String: AnyObject]]
var category: [String: AnyObject]? = categories?[categoryIndex]
```

***Note:** I had to change* `category` *to an* `[String: AnyObject]?`

Comment: I miss the days of Objective C where we don't have to get around the compiler like this when accessing nested dictionary attributes.

Comment: Yeah, type safety comes with some tradeoffs for sure. But, Swift is still in  Beta so chances are stuff like this will improve over time.

Comment: Most of the problem here is the extensive use of `AnyObject`. You shouldn't store a dictionary of `AnyObject` if you can possibly help it. Convert it to typed objects, and almost all of your casting goes away. The most common cause of these dictionaries is JSON parsing, and the solution is to convert your JSON dictionary into structs during parsing. Then Swift becomes much nicer than ObjC for this kind of work (because you can't later crash on the wrong type).

Comment: It is not the parsing of JSON that is the problem, that is done easily with one call. It is accessing the items in the resulting heterogeneous tree structure. There are now a number of solutions and that number is growing, Apple really should provide one solution to this JSON problem. We should not have to spend lots of effort on rather bazar syntax that sidetracks us from our objective of solving our problem. And yes, this was an insecure issue in Objective-C but the current Swift cure is worse than the problem.